# dropping filtered statistics causes deadlocks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, table-statistics, filtered-statistics

We have a large data warehouse database where we continuously get new rows inserted in 5 different tables, at the left(Edit: right)-hand side of the b-tree (=at end of the table)

This means that ordinary statistics very quickly gets outdated, regarding the new data.
So we've changed our insert procedure to also do a CREATE STATISTICS FST_xxx 
with a WHERE clause that covers the latest two million rows.

This has ensured that we do not get incorrect execution plans.
Now we are stranded with hundreds of these.
We have a cleanup job that runs once a day that will drop unneeded statistics.

but this causes a lot of Deadlocks.

Is there a way to disable Filtered Statistics or to drop Filtered Statistics without causing deadlocks?

(edit:) The table is clustered on a Bigint Identity(1,1) asending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you clarify where the rows are getting inserted?  You said left-hand side of the b-tree, but you also said end of the table.  Is it correct to assume this a clustered index you're talking about?  And whether it's clustered or not, is the index key ascending?  Thanks.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. Yes, it is right-hand side, and the table is clustered, on a Bigint Identity(1,1) ascending.

Comment: You may want to consider using trace flag 2389.  There is more information here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianjo/archive/2006/04/24/582227.aspx  and also  https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/statistics-on-ascending-columns/    As with any trace flag, I would recommend testing before you drop it into production.

Comment: Thank you very much for the two links. I'll investigate these trace flags.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try to update the statistics instead of creating a new one every time?

Comment: the tables are quite big, it will take quite some time extract, and incur a lot of extra I/O